# How to center one line of text vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm really sorry to bring this question up since I know there are answers on this. I have read and read and can't seem to make it work. Obviously there's something I'm doing wrong so if you could explain to me what I'm supposed to do and why I'd be really thankful.

```css
footer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Copyright 2016 - Say my name. All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: Instead of a paragraph of apologies, please post a question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` property.
[Vertically centered text](https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

**HTML:**

```
<footer>
  <p>Copyright 2016 - Say my name. All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
footer {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1vh;
}
```

```css
footer {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Copyright 2016 - Say my name. All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```

Or you can use `flex` property,but its not supported by many browser version
[Align using flex property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)

**CSS:**

```
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;        /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;        /*ALIGN VERTICAL*/
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer p {  
   line-height: 1vh;
}
```

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;        /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;        /*ALIGN VERTICAL*/
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer p {
  
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Copyright 2016 - Say my name. All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need paragraph tags within the footer; just add `line-height: 15vh;` to your footer, and remove the surrounding paragraph tags.

```css
footer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  line-height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-top: 1px solid #232323;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  Copyright 2016 - Say my name. All Rights Reserved
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **CSS**:

```
footer {
        display: table-cell; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```